# Laravel 5: How do I change the directory of my custom config file from app/config to app/source?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, config

I have a repository in folder app/source and a second project share the app/source with my current project. I need to move my app/config/config.php into app/source so my second project has the same data. How do I configure laravel to search for my custom config in app/source/config.php instead of app/config/config.php?

I've tried to update my ConfiserviceProvider class to this:

```
class ConfigServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    config([
        'app/source/config.php',
    ]);
}
}
```

but this isn't working.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To include custom config file:

```
app('config')->set('custom', require app_path('source/config.php'));
```

For example if **config.php** file contains:

```
<?php

return [

    'foo' => 'bar'

];
```

Access it like that:

```
config('config.foo'); // return 'bar'
```

Comment: `app('config')->set('custom', require app_path('source/config.php'));` would go under `register()`?

Comment: yes, and remember to include your newly created service provider (`App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider::class`) into config/app.php `providers` array

Comment: you have to configure `config/app.php` to include `ConfigServiceProvider`, and the shared config is located at `app/source/config.php`?